# How to change connection which we get using useConnection hook from solana-wallet-adapter-react?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

```
import { useConnection} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';

const { connection } = useConnection();
```

here, how do we change the connection network? Is there any method like `setConnection` or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the network usually in the ConnectionProvider with the endpoint prop.

````
  // The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
  const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Mainnet;

  // You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
  const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

  const wallets = useMemo(
    () => [
      new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
      new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
      new GlowWalletAdapter(),
      new LedgerWalletAdapter(),
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
};```

And instead of useConnection, you can also define it yourself.

```import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js';```

And then set the connection

```const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', "confirmed")
````

Comment: Yeah, but what's really the point of `useConnection` hook if we can just initialize a new connection object ourselves everytime and the endpoint is not changable in the ConnectionProvider? I'm using some other packages and they use `useConnection` hook, so I can't use my own connection object

Comment: It is changeable.  The network variable will allow you to change between devnet, testnet and mainnet.  If you want to use your own rpc, just adapt the endpoint so it points to your rpc url.